# How can i change JSON object data with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, json, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

A site that I'm using contains a JavaScript file, inside the file it contains a code with JSON and goes like this:

```
$.getJSON(API_URL + getSubdomain() + "/values");
```

The data file contains the code:

```
{"has_clicked_all":false,"has_clicked_already":false,"buttons":

[{"id":3922,"name":"button3992","has_clicked":false},

{"id":4613,"name":"button4613","has_clicked":false},

{"id":4339,"name":"button4339","has_clicked":false},

{"id":4340,"name":"button4340","has_clicked":false},

{"id":4341,"name":"button4341","has_clicked":false},
    {"id":4622,"name":"button4622","has_clicked":false},

{"id":4623,"name":"button4623","has_clicked":false},

{"id":4828,"name":"button4828","has_clicked":false},
    {"id":4829,"name":"button4829","has_clicked":false},

{"id":4861,"name":"button4861","has_clicked":false}]}
```

What I'm wanting to do is change all the value's to true without clicking on all of the buttons. I've tried doing a lot of research and spent 4 hours figuring out how I could do this and me being very new to all this just leaves me stuck... 
I just need someone to give me a hand it would be greatly appreciated! Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the json , modify the data , then re-encode to json

**javascript:**

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
for(i = 0; i < data.buttons.length; i++){
    data.buttons[i].has_clicked = true;
}
data.has_clicked_all = true;
data = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(data);
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gor2z0hr/)

**jQuery :**

```
(function() {
  $.getJSON(API_URL + getSubdomain() + "/values", function(data) {
      data.has_clicked_all = true;
      $.each( data.buttons, function( i, item) {
        data.buttons[i].has_clicked = true;
      });
      data = JSON.stringify(data);
      alert(data);
  });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so does this mean when I load the page it will automatically set the values to true?

Comment: @joe yea this code will change all vbalues to true , that's what you wanted right ?

Comment: Yeah that's absolutely perfect, thank you very much I really do appreciate it I'm going to test it now :).

Comment: hmm, now its saying in the js console:
[05:03:42.998] json is not defined @ file:///C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/dvgqchtj.default/gm_scripts/true/true.user.js:8

[05:03:43.338] json is not defined @ file:///C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/dvgqchtj.default/gm_scripts/true/true.user.js:8

[05:03:47.745] Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'

Comment: @joe refresh my answer I added the jQuery

Comment: Hmm, now the only thing is I'm getting $ is not defined, i added a window interval to keep repeating the script in case it was because  of the script trying to set the values to true before it even loaded but that didn't work.

Comment: wait i solved it, now its saying [05:37:23.574] Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'

Comment: Sorry about this, for your troubles i could donate you $5 or $10 if i get this working if that would be alright?

Comment: @joe this seems to be a bug with mozilla, does the code work beside that. I just tested its fine

Comment: nope, its not working for me the values are just staying the same :/, The source code is different to the actual website I slightly altered it so no one knows what site I'm using, if you have anyway of messaging me i could send you the link to the actual page

Comment: Its http://soulsplit.runetoplist.com/vote ill edit this link and remove it in 5 mins, im trying to set all the values to true so i can click on the continue button and proceed.. you only have to vote on 2 of the 10 sites either way, and the rest you just have to click on because they dont use callbacks. the link to the data file is http://api.runetoplist.com/0.1/soulsplit/vote4rewards

Comment: Im very confused, I visited the link but did not understand, you have google talk for chat ?